# Passing variable to an exception

Tags: java

```
    private static void ignoringExc(RunnableExc r) {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("");
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface RunnableExc {
        void run() throws Exception;
    }
```

I have multiple variables that need to be set into a Person a. However, some variables from Person b may be null. So I use the above function to avoid null pointer exception error. But  I want to customise the error message in log.error() in ignoringExc function, such as "The age of Person B is null". How to do that?

```
ignoringExc(() -> a.setAddress(b.getPerson("address")));
ignoringExc(() -> a.setName(b.getPerson("name")));
ignoringExc(() -> a.setAge(b.getPerson("age")));
...
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `Person` class?  Or, at least an outline.

Comment: it would be better to not rely on Exceptions to check for `null`... this can eventually hide some errors, like something else being `null` (e.g. `a` or `b`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in a `String` as well. This is common practice for some of the precondition tools in Java. Take a look at [`Objects#requireNonNull(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) vs [`Objects#requireNonNull(T,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)).

So, like this.

```java
    private static void ignoringExc(RunnableExc r, String message) {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(message);
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface RunnableExc {
        void run() throws Exception;
    }
```

Which would then allow you to do this.

```java
ignoringExc(() -> a.setAddress(b.getPerson("address")), "address message");
ignoringExc(() -> a.setName(b.getPerson("name")),       "name message");
ignoringExc(() -> a.setAge(b.getPerson("age")),         "age message");
...
```

Comment: I have tried this, but then it will get "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" error

Comment: I just tested it, and it worked for me. Can you try copy and pasting my code exactly as is over your equivalent methods? And when it fails, show me the exact lines of code. You can edit your original question with the exact lines of code, then ping me here to let me know that you did so.

Comment: Thank you. I just change the order of the parameters from  '''String message, RunnableExc r''' to '''RunnableExc r, String message''' and it works now!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let me know if any other issues come up

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using `NullPointerException` to do null checks. Throwing an exception is relatively expensive, as @user16320675 points out, other NPE's may occur, and you are also catching `Exception` which will ignore other problems.

Instead, use a function like:

```
    static <T> void setIfNotNull(T value, Consumer<T> setter) {
        if (value != null) {
            setter.accept(value);
        } else {
            // logging if needed
        }
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
        setIfNotNull(b.getName(), a::setName);
```

Of course you could also consider making the setters on `A` silently ignore `null` instead of throwing an exception, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: I have tried this method but it still throws an exception error. For my case, my getter is like this b.getName().getString("surname"). How can I handle this case? @tgdavies

Comment: the null error occurs in this getName, not getString. so when running the code, it directly skips calling the "setIfNotNull" method and throws the error from this line: setIfNotNull(b.getName(), a::setName); @tgdavies

Comment: This is completely different to the scenario in your question, where the exception was being thrown by the setter.

Comment: if for this case, is using NullPointerException the suitable way to solve it? @tgdavies

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your actual code.

Comment: My code is like this '''a.setAddress(b.getPerson("address").getString("Stress");
a.setAddress(b.getPerson("address").getString("Country");
a.setName(b.getPerson("name").getString("Surname");'''
getPerson with a specific value may get a null value, getString as well. So, how can i catch run these without using notpotinerexception